# What are some quadratic run time tasks (algorithms)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, lower-bounds

Are there problems, for which best algorithms have worst run time O(input_length^2) and it is proven, that this worst time cannot be substantially improved (better algorithms do not exist).

EDIT: This question is different from [Are there any known lower-bounds for complexity on Non-determinsitic machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59487/are-there-any-known-lower-bounds-for-complexity-on-non-determinsitic-machines) , because I have in mind deterministic machine. For example, simple one-processor computer. Question [Problems that provably require quadratic time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/problems-that-provably-require-quadratic-time) is more like this.

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38357/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30320/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6732/755, and [tag:lower-bounds].

Comment: @D.W. Definitely not a dupe of the question about nondeterministic machines!

Comment: @DavidRicherby, it's not the same *question*, but the answer to that question answers this one as well (that answer covers deterministic machines as well).  DSblizzard, take another look at the answer to that question -- I think you'll find it contains all the information needed to answer this question too.